# ffmpeg combine audio mix code into complex concate script

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I got currently 2 different ffmpeg scripts which I want to combine. I do not have good ffmpeg experience and those codes are mostly googel code so please be patient with me

The first code is concating 3 videos:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "$vid1" -i "$fp" -i "$vid1" -filter_complex \
"[0:v]scale=$cResolution:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=$cResolution:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v0]; \
 [1:v]scale=$cResolution:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=$cResolution:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v1]; \
 [2:v]scale=$cResolution:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=$cResolution:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v2]; \
 [0:a]aformat=sample_rates=48000:channel_layouts=stereo[a0]; \
 [1:a]aformat=sample_rates=48000:channel_layouts=stereo[a1]; \
 [2:a]aformat=sample_rates=48000:channel_layouts=stereo[a2]; \
 [v0][a0][v1][a1][v2][a2]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]; \
 [v]drawtext=text='example..':y=h-line_h-$h3:x=w/30*mod(t\,20):enable='gt(mod(t,$dr2),$Introdr_rounded)'[v]; \
 [v]drawtext=text='example..':y=h-line_h-$hcentral:x=w/20*mod(t\,100):enable='gt(mod(t,$dr2),$Introdr_rounded)'[v]; \
 [v]drawtext=text='example..':y=h-line_h-23:x=w/30*mod(t\,20):enable='gt(mod(t,$dr2),$Introdr_rounded)'[v]" \
 -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -preset veryfast -c:a aac -movflags +faststart "$fp_dest"
```

The second code is overlay a background mp3 in endless loop to the created video from above. Its important to know that this code does overlap the audio of the video and does not replace it. In future I will lower the volume of the mp3 files to work as background music

```
ffmpeg -y -i "$fp_dest" -filter_complex "amovie=$audio:loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB[aud];[0:a][aud]amix[a]" -map 0:v -map '[a]' -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 256k -shortest ./test.mp4
```

So currently I got 2 steps which I want to combine into 1 step. Can you please help me to include the second code into the first one without change any logic of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use amix to mix the music and the concated audio. `stream_loop` is applied to the music to loop it.

```
ffmpeg -y -i "$vid1" -i "$fp" -i "$vid1" -stream_loop -1 -i "$audio" -filter_complex \
"[0:v]scale=$cResolution:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=$cResolution:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v0]; \
 [1:v]scale=$cResolution:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=$cResolution:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v1]; \
 [2:v]scale=$cResolution:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=$cResolution:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v2]; \
 [0:a]aformat=sample_rates=48000:channel_layouts=stereo[a0]; \
 [1:a]aformat=sample_rates=48000:channel_layouts=stereo[a1]; \
 [2:a]aformat=sample_rates=48000:channel_layouts=stereo[a2]; \
 [v0][a0][v1][a1][v2][a2]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]; \
 [a][3]amix=duration=first[a]; \
 [v]drawtext=text='example..':y=h-line_h-$h3:x=w/30*mod(t\,20):enable='gt(mod(t,$dr2),$Introdr_rounded)'[v]; \
 [v]drawtext=text='example..':y=h-line_h-$hcentral:x=w/20*mod(t\,100):enable='gt(mod(t,$dr2),$Introdr_rounded)'[v]; \
 [v]drawtext=text='example..':y=h-line_h-23:x=w/30*mod(t\,20):enable='gt(mod(t,$dr2),$Introdr_rounded)'[v]" \
 -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -preset veryfast -c:a aac -b:a 256k -movflags +faststart "$fp_dest"
```

Comment: thank you mate! sadly I cant upvote cause low amount of rep.. but you are a real ffmpeg hero.. I found so many solutions based on your answers on different stackoverflow posts too! You saved my life! Keep up the good work!